# communicating between functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a school project and I need some help communicating between functions. This is what I have got so far

```
def difficuilty():
level = 0
while level >=4 or level == 0:
    level = int(input("Please enter the difficulty (1/2/3)"))
    if level == 1:
        yesNo = input("you have chosen difficulty 1, is this correct? ")
        if yesNo.upper() == 'Y':
            level  = 1
        elif yesNo.upper() == 'N':
            level  = 4
        else:
            print ("You have entered the wrong thing")
    elif level == 2:
        yesNo = input("you have chosen difficulity 2, is this correct? ")
        if yesNo.upper() == 'Y':
            level  = 2
        elif yesNo.upper() == 'N':
            level  = 4
        else:
            print ("You have entered the wrong thing")
    elif level == 3:
        yesNo = input("you have chosen difficulity 3, is this correct? ")
        if yesNo.upper() == 'Y':
            level  = 3
        elif yesNo.upper() == 'N':
            level  = 4
        else:
            print ("You have entered the wrong thing")

return level 


def question(level):
    if level == 1:
        print ("hi")

def main():

    getName()
    difficulty()
    question(level)
```

I am trying to get the variable 'level' from the difficulty function to go into the question function so I can use it, when I run the program, it gives me an error which says 'NameError: Name 'level is not defined'. Can someone please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `level` is only defined within the scope of your two functions, but not at the scope of `main()`. You have to define a variable (called `level`) within the scope of `main()` in order to access it. Try:

```
def main():
    getName()
    level = difficulty()
    question(level)
```

This way, the variable that is returned from `difficulty()` (named `level` within `difficulty()`) is accessible to `main()`.

Also, is this your actual code? I notice some mistakes, like `difficulty()` being spelled two different ways, and a lack of indentation within `difficuilty()`, that will have unexpected results if you run this. Please post your verbatim code if you have it so that it's easier to tell what the specific problem is.

Comment: also, getName is not defined

Comment: I fixed the spelling mistakes. And the I cut off the getName function when I posted this

Comment: @JamesBramley Ok, would you mind editing your question to include your full code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the value of level that is returned from your difficult function

```
def main():
    getName()
    level = difficulty()
    question(level)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but in Python you don't use `def` for variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `global` method does just that, it turns the local arg used within a function to a global one callable by all means.

```
def difficuilty():
    level = 0
    while level >=4 or level == 0:
        level = int(input("Please enter the difficulty (1/2/3)"))
        global level
```

That way (level) will be callable. One last thing, given your application I would go with Milo's answer, because using `global` method can have its cons.